# Scraping Amazon Prices and matching against entries in spreadsheet

Tags: web-scraping

In my job I currently compare wholesale items (sent to us from suppliers in CSV format) to Amazon listings to find profitable items for the business.

I want to build a tool to help me with this very manual process. I know basic Python but what other languages or packages could help me with this?

I imagine I'd need to load the CSV, do column matching (as these will differ across suppliers) then somehow scan amazon for the same products and scrape pricing information.

I'd also like whatever I build to look nice/be really user friendly so I can share it with my colleague.

I'm willing to put in the work to learn myself and know I might have to put in a fair amount of learning but a nudge in the right direction / a list of key skills I should research would be much appreciated.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: I made some edits/improvements to my answer, to allow even products without prices listed. Feel free to ask questions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function in R to get all matching products and prices from amazon via their search terms.

```r
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

price_xpath <- ".//parent::a/parent::h2/parent::div/following-sibling::div//a/span[not(@class='a-price a-text-price')]/span[@class='a-offscreen']"
description_xpath <- "//div/h2/a/span"

get_amazon_info <- function(item) {
  source_html <- read_html(str_c("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=", str_replace_all(item, " ", "+")))

  root_nodes <- source_html %>%
    html_elements(xpath = description_xpath)
  
  prices <- xml_find_all(root_nodes, xpath = price_xpath, flatten = FALSE)
  prices <- lapply(prices, function(x) html_text(x)[1])
  prices[lengths(prices) == 0] <- NA

  tibble(product = html_text(root_nodes),
         price = unlist(prices, use.names = FALSE)) %>%
    mutate(price = parse_number(str_remove(price, "\\$")))
}
get_amazon_info("dog food")

# # A tibble: 67 × 2
#    product                                                                                                            price
#    <chr>                                                                                                              <dbl>
#  1 Purina Pro Plan High Protein Dog Food with Probiotics for Dogs, Shredded Blend Turkey & Rice Formula - 17 lb. Bag   45.7
#  2 Purina Pro Plan High Protein Dog Food With Probiotics for Dogs, Shredded Blend Chicken & Rice Formula - 35 lb. Bag  64.0
#  3 Rachael Ray Nutrish Premium Natural Dry Dog Food, Real Chicken & Veggies Recipe, 28 Pounds (Packaging May Vary)     40.0
#  4 Blue Buffalo Life Protection Formula Natural Adult Dry Dog Food, Chicken and Brown Rice 34-lb                       69.0
#  5 Blue Buffalo Life Protection Formula Natural Adult Dry Dog Food, Chicken and Brown Rice 30-lb                       61.0
#  6 Purina ONE Natural Dry Dog Food, SmartBlend Lamb & Rice Formula - 8 lb. Bag                                         14.0
#  7 Purina ONE High Protein Senior Dry Dog Food, +Plus Vibrant Maturity Adult 7+ Formula - 31.1 lb. Bag                 44.4
#  8 Purina Pro Plan Weight Management Dog Food, Shredded Blend Chicken & Rice Formula - 34 lb. Bag                      66.0
#  9 NUTRO NATURAL CHOICE Large Breed Adult Dry Dog Food, Chicken & Brown Rice Recipe Dog Kibble, 30 lb. Bag             63.0
# 10 NUTRO NATURAL CHOICE Healthy Weight Adult Dry Dog Food, Chicken & Brown Rice Recipe Dog Kibble, 30 lb. Bag          63.0
# # … with 57 more rows
```

If you are new to R, you will have to `install.packages("tidyverse")` first.

After `library(tidyverse)`, you can `read_csv` the products file, and execute the following commands as so. Replace the sample data with the `read_csv` command.

```r
products <- tribble(~item,
                    "best books",
                    "flour",
                    "dog food") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(amazon = map(item, get_amazon_info)) %>%
  unnest(everything())

# # A tibble: 208 × 3
#    item       product                                                                                                  price
#    <chr>      <chr>                                                                                                    <dbl>
#  1 best books Takeaway Quotes for Coaching Champions for Life: The Process of Mentoring the Person, Athlete and Player 15.0 
#  2 best books The Art of War (Deluxe Hardbound Edition)                                                                15.3 
#  3 best books Turbulent: A Post Apocalyptic EMP Survival Thriller (Days of Want Series Book 1)                         13.0 
#  4 best books Revenge at Sea (Quint Adler Thrillers Book 1)                                                             0   
#  5 best books The Family Across the Street: A totally unputdownable psychological thriller with a shocking twist        9.89
#  6 best books Where the Crawdads Sing                                                                                   9.98
#  7 best books The Seven Husbands of Evelyn Hugo: A Novel                                                                9.42
#  8 best books Addlestone: The Addlestone Chronicles Book 1 October 1St 1934 - July 20Th 1935                            4.99
#  9 best books The Wife Before: A Spellbinding Psychological Thriller with a Shocking Twist                             13.6 
# 10 best books Wish You Were Here: A Novel                                                                              11.0 
# # … with 198 more rows
```

As you are new to StackOverflow, please remember to hit the green check mark if this helps. Please add some more tags to your post, and change the title to "Scraping Amazon Prices".